# Please link “How to Ask in Private Beta” on private beta sites

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, private-beta, asking-questions

Before asking a question on a private beta site, I need to click through [“How to Ask in Private Beta”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask-beta). That's good.

I also need to click when asking on Meta; I don't get the point but it's not really a problem.

Once I've clicked on it once, I can't find a link to that page any more. It's not linked from the FAQ. It's not linked from the “Ask Question” page. It doesn't seem to be linked anywhere.

Please link to “How to Ask in Private Beta” from the “obvious” places, at least from the sidebar in the “Ask Question” page, as long as a site is in private beta.

Comment: A lot of the stuff on that page wouldn't be out of place on the "real" "How to Ask" page either.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Good idea!

I am linking the how to ask from the sidebar to the proper page for a private beta.